# How do you remove the first instance of an element value in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

> Add a method void removeFirst(int newVal) to the IntegerList class that removes the first occurrence of a value from the list. If the value does not appear in the list, it should do nothing (but it's not an error). Removing an item should not change the size of the array, but note that the array values do need to remain contiguous, so when you remove a value you will have to shift everything after it down to fill up its space. Also remember to decrement the variable that keeps track of the number of elements.

Please help, I have tried all of the other solutions listed on this site regarding "removing an element from an array" and none have worked.

Comment: Read the question, it says: "when you remove a value you will have to shift everything after it down to fill up its space". Do you understand what this sentence means? This is the key to your solution.

Comment: The answer might be easier if people know what language you are programming in...  also is the underlying datastructure actually an array? or is a linked list?

Comment: it is an array, not a linked list.  This in java.  I assume that this means that the index of the remaining elements must remain contiguous from 0 - array.length.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as so

Comment: `newVal` suggest a new value to be added, rather than removed.

Comment: Suggesting someone adds 'homework' tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This method supports the same functionality as Collection.remove() which is how an ArrayList removes the first matching element.

```
public boolean remove(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (array[i] != n) continue;
        size--;
        System.arraycopy(array, i + 1, array, i, size - i);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Rather than write this code yourself, I suggest you look at Trove4J's `TIntArrayList` which is a wrapper for `int[]` You can also read the code for ArrayList to see how it is written.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
 int count; //No of elements in the array
 for(i=0;i<count;i++) 
 {
     if(Array[i]==element )
     {
          swap(Array,i,count);
            if(count)
            --count;
            break;  
     } 


 }
 int  swap(int Array[],int i,int count)
 {
     int j;
       for(j=i;j<=count-i;j++)
       a[i]=a[i+1];

 }
```

This is not the Full Implementation.You have to create a class and do this.

Comment: +0: This would work, but is fairly expensive. Swap could be called shuffle. ;) The `if(count)` doesn't compile or do anything.

Comment: `System.arraycopy` should be used in this case

Answer (score 0):

Using the method below

```
public static <TypeOfObject> TypeOfObject[] removeFirst(TypeOfObject[] array, TypeOfObject valueToRemove) {
    TypeOfObject[] result = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length - 1);
    List<TypeOfObject> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    tempList.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    tempList.remove(valueToRemove);
    return tempList.toArray(result);
}
```

You can remove the first element of any array by calling the method as demonstrated in the below JUnit test.

```
@Test
public void removeFirstTest() {
    // Given
    Integer valToRemove = 5;
    Integer[] input = {1,2,3,valToRemove,4,valToRemove,6,7,8,9};
    Integer[] expected = {1,2,3,4,valToRemove,6,7,8,9};
    
    // When
    Integer[] actual = removeFirst(input, valToRemove);
    
    // Then
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(expected, actual);
}
```